# Получить мою геолокацию

Tags: python, геолокация

Всем привет, уже перепробовал множество РАЗЛИЧНЫХ способов узнать свои координаты.
Использовал python модули и сайты типа 2ip, много различных сайтов.
Всё выше перечисленное выдаёт мне эти координаты(55.7522 37.6156).
Тестил я всё это с разных устройств, у которых разный провайдер.
От этого(55.7522 37.6156) места я нахожусь очень далеко, но нахожусь в Москве(хоть что-то я выявил правильно).

Примеры кода

```py
import geocoder
g = geocoder.ip('me')
print(g.latlng)
```

```bsh
curl ipinfo.io/loc
```

Ещё я зашёл на сайт 2ip, узнал свой ipv4, зашёл на сайты: ipinfo.io, 2ip.ru/geoip, iplocation.net/;
Вбил туда(на сайты) свой ipv4, получил прежний результат.
Кто нибудь знает как выявить подлинное местоположение?
Желательно использовать python.
Если вы знаете способ без использования python, пишите, буду очень признателен. 
Пожалуйста, помогите.
Спасибо

Comment: опишите точнее как вы получали неверные координаты, приведите пример кода, расширьте вопрос в общем

Comment: А на каком устройстве вы это пытаетесь сделать и есть ли у него GPS ?

Comment: Пытался я это всё сделать на ноутбуках и телефонах

Comment: Дело в том, что вы получаете координаты вашего провайдера. Получить именно ваши координаты не представляется возможным, если вы не из органов власти.

Comment: Вообще ни какой лазейки нет?

Comment: Есть же инструменты как seeker которые работают через ngrok и прекрасно справляются со своей работой

Comment: Я правильно понял, вы через IP адрес пытаетесь получить координаты своей  местоположения?

Comment: Да, я пытаюсь это сделать со своим месторасположением.

Answer (score 0):

Передайте в геокодер мак адреса соседних точек доступа wifi. Точность определения в Москве улучшится до 50 метров

Вот так делал в роутере. Там питона нет, только cgi..

собрать уровни сигнала wifi

```
iwlist wlan0 scan | awk '/Address/ {print $5} /Signal\ level/{split($3,a,"="); print a[2]}' > levels.list
```

Формирую xml. На питоне это будет намного проще

```
xml=<ya_lbs_request><common><version>1.0</version>
<api_key>Ваш ключ</api_key>
</common><wifi_networks>
<?$i=0; $levels = fopen("/tmp/levels.list", "r") >
<? while(!feof($levels)) >
<? $i++; $mac = fgets($levels,255); $level = fgets($levels,255) >
<network><mac><? echo $mac></mac><signal_strength><? echo $level></signal_strength><age><? echo $i*10+1000 ></age></network>
<? endwhile >
</wifi_networks></ya_lbs_request>
```

И отправляю в Яндекс. На питоне через requests просто отправить постом

```
cgi -q /usr/www/lib/ya.xml.cgi | curl -d @- -X POST http://api.lbs.yandex.net/geolocation > $LOC
```

В ответ получаю координаты

Документация тут
https://yandex.ru/dev/locator/doc/dg/api/xml-docpage/

https://yandex.ru/dev/locator/doc/dg/api/json.html/

Comment: Здравствуйте! 1) Яндекс локатор вроде должен ещё принимать сотовые вышки. 2) У меня винда. Можете показать levels.list, я попробую сформирую файл с такой же структурой.

Comment: @Nikto структура levels list промежуточная, если хотите формировать, то формируйте сразу xml. Описание есть в доках

Comment: Тут в примере на php первой или второй версии) встройка в роутер с заводской прошивкой. В винде это будет проще в разы

Comment: а что делать с сотами(сотовыми вышками? Я лично не знаю как найти ближайшую соту через python или php. В документации сказано что хоть одна сота должна быть

Comment: + Я предпочитаю json. https://yandex.ru/dev/locator/doc/dg/api/json.html/.

Comment: Я это сделал! Но меня напрягает то, что я не передал соты. Результаты вроде точные.

Comment: Результаты супер точные:)

Comment: А yandex locator будет работать в за пределами россии(в сша например)?

Comment: В США попробуй использовать подобный сервис от гугла. В России и Турции яндекс точнее. Соты нужны там где нет вайфая. По ним точность меньше - метров 300 в городе, 1-5 км за городом.

Comment: @Nikto работать будет везде, где прошел человек с навигатором от яндекс или проехало яндекс такси

Comment: да спасибо. Сначала я пробовал использовать такой же сервис от google. Но результаты оказались ннточные. Потом пересел на Яндекс. И кстати, подобное api от Гугла платное.

Comment: @Nikto у яндекса тоже платное, если использовать в комерческих целях или тиражировать в приложениях.

Comment: а где это написано? И сколько запросов в месяц/неделю или в день я могу отправлять бесплатно?

Comment: @Nikto яндекс не раскрывает количество запросов чтоб не подменяли пачками apikey бесплатные. Но запросов можно сделать очень много.

Comment: Хм, в тарифах нет. Значит пока бесплатный. Для тиражирования есть несколько условий https://yandex.ru/legal/locator_api/